# unexpected "focusout" event trigering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to show text box (#dimVal), when div(#CanvasArea) is clicked. And I want to make this text box disappear, when it loses its focus.

```
    <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id = "CanvasArea", style = "width:50%; height:600px; border:2px; border-color:orange; border-style:solid; float:left">
    <h3>Click Me</h3>
    </div>

    <input type="text", id="dimVal", value="111", style="position:absolute; display:none; left:300px; top:300px" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    onMouseDown = function(e){
        $("#dimVal").show();
        $("#dimVal").focus();
        $("#dimVal").focusout(onLostFocus);
    }

    onLostFocus = function(e){
        $("#dimVal").hide();
        $("#dimVal").unbind("focusout");
    }

    $("#CanvasArea").bind("mousedown", onMouseDown);
    </script>

    </body>
```

I wonder why "focusout" event fires right after mouseclick?

Comment: It seems, I find solution. Just replace

$("#CanvasArea").bind("mousedown", onMouseDown);
with
$("#CanvasArea").bind("mouseup", onMouseDown);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to get your code to work in its current form, so I rewrote it somewhat using the jQuery mouseup function and the newest version of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#CanvasArea").mouseup(function() {
    $("#dimVal").show();
    $("#dimVal").focus();
    $("#dimVal").focusout(onLostFocus);
});

onLostFocus = function(e){
    $("#dimVal").hide();
    $("#dimVal").unbind("focusout");
}
});
```

this works as intended, shows up when canvas area is clicked and removes focus when the user clicks off the form.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your mouse is over the `CanvasArea` at the time you give focus to the `dimVal` hence `dimVal` immediately loses focus after gaining it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `mousedown` to `click` event because before `click` event `mousedown` event triggers and then your code is executed which sets the focus onto textbox, after the `click` event is triggered the focus is lost so the `focusout` event is triggered. Also make use of anonymous function instead of having global functions. Try this.

```
$("#CanvasArea").bind("click", function(e){
    $("#dimVal").focusout(function(e){
        $(this).hide().unbind("focusout");
    }).show().focus();
});
```